# Getting cpu usage data using react and node

Tags: node.js, reactjs, module

Is it possible to use nodes os.cpus() module on react?
Trying to figure out how to get real time cpu usage updates from node on a project on working on. I have played around with react before but i am still a newb and i haven't touched on node yet, so this is proving to be difficult for me.

update: I need the cpu data to be displayed in the site i am making

Comment: React application runs on the browser. You can use browser's dev tools to see performance of your react code.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Sorry if i wasn't clear enough but i need the cpu data to display on the site i am making. Ill update my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the stats of the server system through an API call.

However, to get the stats of the client system is not possible as browsers are supposed to be run in sandbox mode to stop websites from reading the client system or changing it.